# NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed still caching

Tags: amazon-s3, uikit, nsurlrequest, http-caching

I have a JSON file on S3 I'm downloading over HTTP with an NSURLConnection. I set the connection to use a caching policy of `NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed` but I was still seeing an old version of the data come back. I changed to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` and the caching behaviour works.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mistake by not understanding the difference between `NSURLCachedStoragePolicy` and `NSURLRequestCachePolicy`, please see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24783824/1800915

Answer (score 1):

As of today, it looks like `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` is actually doing nothing. From NSURLRequest.h in OS 10.9.1:

[image: Screenshot of NSURLRequest.h]

It looks like the best bet may be to use `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` instead. (Unless Apple simply forgot to update its header file to remove that comment.)