# NSMutableURLRequest returns old values even cachePolicy is NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableurlrequest, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

Im using codes posted here:
[connection release method in connectionDidFinishLoading, causes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559573/connection-release-method-in-connectiondidfinishloading-causes-error)

now first execute returns didFail log.
second execute; returns old response data.
albeit my (localhost) server is totally offline.
and cachePolicy is NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed  (check the code on the link I posted above)

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request=
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:3.0f];
```

the response data seems cached somewhere and still exists.

but if I use NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData //which is commented as -not implemented-

not returns old cache.

but if so **what is the difference between:

NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

and

NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed**

what shall I do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351491/how-to-wait-response-and-parse-xml-done-in-afnetworking-ios/18351761#18351761

Comment: rest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18245461/ios-restkit-application-design/18246517#18246517

Answer (score 2):

`NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed` refers to `NSCachedURLResponse` and is an value of enum `NSURLCacheStoragePolicy`. Since the cache policy of `NSMutableURLRequest` is also an enum (`NSURLRequestCachePolicy`) you just pass wrong int to the static method creating `NSMutableURLRequest`. In this case `NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed` is just 2 which equals to `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad` - and that is why you get old data.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

NSString *Post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Post Parameters"];
        NSURL *Url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Url"];

```
    NSData *PostData = [Post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [PostData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [Request setURL:Url];
    [Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [Request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [Request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [Request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [Request setHTTPBody:PostData];
  NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *Result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:Request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    if (!Result)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    else
    {
       //Parse the result
    }
```

Comment: your example is synchronous.thus it hangs application till server receiving finalized.
Question is why NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed allows ?
it still returns old cache data if server is offline.
your answers are not relevant to question.
I dont want a way to pass this with another method.
I wanto learn the reason.